# Files for molecules to Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, materials-design

where can I find a file for molecules e.g: H2

For solids, I am using AMCSD (American Mineralogist Crystal Structure Database), but where can I find molecule files?

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to create input of $\ce{H2}$ molecule inside QE input file directly or Generate cif or xyz file using **ASE**, **VESTA**, **ATOMSK** and other tool

```
from ase import build
model=build.molecule('H2',vacuum=5)
model.write('H2.cif',format='cif')
```

**QE input**

```
&control
    calculation = 'relax'
    prefix = 'h2'
    pseudo_dir = '/home/anonymous/quantumEspresso_2019/SSSP_precision_pseudos'
/
&system
    ibrav=1, celldm(1) =20, 
    nat=2, ntyp=1,
    ecutwfc=30.0
/
&electrons
    conv_thr=1e-8
/
&ions
    ion_dynamics='bfgs'
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
 H  1.00784  H_ONCV_PBE-1.0.oncvpsp.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)
 H 0.00 0.00 0.00
 H 1.00 0.00 0.00
K_POINTS (automatic)
  1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: When do you used this code:
"model=build.molecule('H2',vacuum=5)
model.write('H2.cif',format='cif')" An XYZ file was created?

Comment: Its cif format. There are several format you can export, check ase manual.

Answer (score 6):

If you need structures for other, more complex, molecules, you can use several online databases like:

## [ZINC](https://zinc.docking.org/)

> Welcome to ZINC, a free database of commercially-available compounds
> for virtual screening. ZINC contains over 230 million purchasable
> compounds in ready-to-dock, 3D formats. ZINC also contains over 750
> million purchasable compounds you can search for analogs in under a
> minute.

## [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/)

> ChemSpider is a free chemical structure database providing fast text
> and structure search access to over 100 million structures from
> hundreds of data sources.

You can download your structure from one of these sites and then convert to QE input format.